# Django in docker cookiecutter - can't send email

Tags: django, docker, cookiecutter-django

I have following docker file

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  production_postgres_data: {}
  production_postgres_data_backups: {}
  production_caddy: {}
  ghotel_cc_production_static_vol: {}

services:
  django: &django
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: ghotel_cc_api_production_django
    volumes:
      - production_static_vol:/app/static
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    command: /start

  postgres:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: api_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - production_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - production_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres

  caddy:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/caddy/Dockerfile
    image: api_production_caddy
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - production_caddy:/root/.caddy
      - ghotel_cc_production_static_vol:/app/static
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.caddy
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8550:80"
```

The problem is that email cannot be sent. There is no errors, Django part works well - i see correct output in console. But after Django sends email it is just lost - never arrives to recipient.

How to correctly configure docker so the email can be sent ?

Comment: did this work with out docker?

Comment: yes, same code works without docker.